# QuickSight could not generate any output column after applying transformation Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-quicksight

I am running a query that works perfectly on AWS Athena however when I use athena as a data source from quicksight and tries to run query it keeps on giving me `QuickSight could not generate any output column after applying transformation` error message.

Here is my query:

```
 WITH register as (
    select created_at as register_time
         , serial_number
         , node_name
         , node_visible_time_name
      from table1
     where type = 'register'),
bought as (
    select created_at as bought_time 
         , node_name
         , serial_number
      from table1
     where type= 'bought')
   SELECT r.node_name
        , r.serial_number
        , r.register_time
        , b.bought_time 
        , r.node_visible_time_name
     FROM register r
LEFT JOIN bought b
       ON r.serial_number = b.serial_number
      AND r.node_name = b.node_name
      AND b.bought_time between r.deploy_time and date(r.deploy_time + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
     LIMIT 11;
```

I've did some search and found similar question [Quicksight custom query postgresql functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58077766/quicksight-custom-query-postgresql-functions) In this case adding INTERVAL '1' DAY had the problem. I've tried other alternatives but no luck. Furthermore running query without it still outputs same error message.

No other lines seems to be getting transformed in any other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-creating dataset and running exact same query works.

I think queries that has been ran on existing dataset transforms the data. Please let me know if anyone knows why this is so.

Comment: I was getting the same error message with some valid SQL and recreating the dataset fixed it for me as well. QuickSight sure could use a better message for this...