# Running a custom SQL in AWS Quicksight using PostgreSQL as a data source

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to run a custom query to visualize in Quicksight. I have tested my query using JetBrain's DataGrip, but failed to return the result in Quicksight. I, then, realized that some SQL functions cause error in Quicksight.

I have run these functions below one by one in Quicksight and got the following error.

```
select current_date;
select to_date('2020-10-10', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
select now();
select now() + '-1 day';
```

Error:
Failed to Prepare Data Set
QuickSight could not generate any output column after applying transformation. Check transform(s) and try again.

I have found one similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58077766/quicksight-custom-query-postgresql-functions), but that didn't help me.
How can I run these functions in Quicksight when the data source is PostgreSQL?